# CloudKit: Error saving record with CKModifyRecordsOperation

Tags: ios, cloudkit

```
<CKError 0x14d8cb70: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; partial errors: {
    B5DEF0B5-F064-4B27-9C89-BE75C9134297:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x14d83b70: "Server Record Changed" (14/2037); "Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x15748cd0; B5DEF0B5-F064-4B27-9C89-BE75C9134297:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Protection data didn't match">
}>
```

I get this error, when try to save `CKRecord`s up to `CloudKit`. Any idea?

Do I have to fetch first records like in convenience API?

I am using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` method to update more record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are planning to do an update, you first need to read the record, make the changes and then write the record. You got a notification that the record was changed in the time between reading and writing the record.

If the version of a record on the server is newer than the version you tried to save, the server returns a CKErrorServerRecordChanged error. The userInfo dictionary of the error object contains the different versions of the conflicting records. Use these keys to retrieve the records and to perform whatever resolution logic is needed to resolve the conflict.

As discussed below in your case the problem was that you persisted the object to a database and recreated the CKRecord to do the modification. In that case you need to persist the system fields using CKRecord encodeSystemFieldsWithCoder. And recreate the CKRecord by initializing it with a NSCoder. You could use the NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver for saving a CKRecord and recreating it. If you need a sample, see the fromCKRecord and toCKRecord methods at the bottom of https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDao.swift

Comment: for 1 record it is ok, but for updating 100-s of records, is it serious I have to download first, find which one how to modify, and upload ?? brbrbr

Comment: You don't have to read them again. see my updated answer. So just save them all and try the update again when you get an error using the record ID's inside the error

Comment: You can use `-[CKRecord encodeSystemFieldsWithCoder:]` to encode just the system fields (like the change tag) for a record. You can later unarchive the record with just the system fields, apply just the changes you want saved to the server, and save the record. If you're already keeping a local database of records that should save you a round trip to the server.

Comment: I do as you say, (1) **reading** (2) **modifying** CKRecords (3) **saving**, and I do it with a certain set of records quite frequently, and sometimes I receive only part of the records, not all for what I specified condition in `CKQuery`'s predicate, do you know why?

Comment: The result that is returned by CloudKit is limited. The standard number of records seems to be 100, but that can vary depending on how the total load on iCloud is. If you use a SKQueryOperation, then you can influence the number of records that needs to be returned by setting .resultsLimit The default value for that is CKQueryOperationMaximumResults

Comment: I am updating frequently max 5 records, I don't think it is a limit issue .. but can it be that even a saving is completed on client, and next reading iteration **can and will** start just after saving completion, CloudKit haven't rely finish operation?!

Comment: The default behavior of CKModifyRecordsOperation is atomic. (see atomic property) So if one update fails then all should fail. The moment records are written and the result was ok, then any query after that should include these changed records. But hey... I have seen stranger things/bugs in CloudKit. So when you sure your code is OK and you still often don't get a complete response, you should file a Radar

Comment: You should use the NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver for saving a CKRecord and recreating it. If you need a sample, see the fromCKRecord and toCKRecord methods at the bottom of https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDao.swift

Comment: I don't think Apple intends for us to archive CKRecord:s as is, or I am missing something. AFAIK they want us to use our own data structures. As I understand it, that would implicitly mean that we should not save/cache CKRecord:s, (just the system fields using encodeSystemFieldsWithCoder).

Comment: To what extent would using the "[desired keys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation/1515268-desiredkeys#)" property of `CKQueryOperation` alleviate the problem of "100s of records" being updated?

Comment: @AmitaiB Even if you only update 1 field, the record will be updated. The change token is for the entire record. So if you retrieve only half the fields and the update is in the other fields, then the record is still considered as updated and you will have to do a reread even if the change is not in your fields.

Comment: So it'll save space (bandwidth, memory, storage), but not time, then. Thanks